# В чем разница между словами "заснуть" и "уснуть" и есть ли она?

Tags: лингвистика

-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это синонимы. Но поскольку оба слова многозначные, синонимия наблюдается лишь в некоторых значениях.
**ЗАСНУТЬ 1**. Погрузиться в сон. *Ребёнок заснул. Крепко заснуть. Заснуть после принятия  лекарства. Заснуть глубоким, тревожным сном. Заснуть, склонившись над книгой.* **2**. Стать безлюдным; замереть, затихнуть. *Город заснул. В селе всё заснуло. Природа заснула до весны.* **3**. *только 3 л. Разг.* Перестать дышать, умереть (о рыбе). Сом заснул. Заснувшие караси. 
 ◊ *Заснуть вечным (последним, могильным и т. п.) сном.*

**УСНУТЬ 1.** Погрузиться в сон; заснуть. *Спокойно уснуть. Долго не мог уснуть. Уснуть крепким сном. Уснуть за столом.* **2.** Перестать дышать, умереть (о рыбе). *Пойманная рыба скоро уснула. Окунь быстро уснул.* **3.** Погрузиться в тишину, безмолвие, покой; перестать шуметь, казаться безжизненным (о явлениях). *Ночные улицы уснули. Река уснула. Всё в природе уснуло.* **4.** Перестать проявляться; ослабеть, притупиться (о чувстве). *Уснула ненависть. Уснуло горе. Уснула любовь.* **5.** Умереть. Тихо уснул. Уснул вечным, последним, могильным сном. Уснул навеки, навсегда.

Как видите, синонимия наблюдается в трех первых значениях этих глаголов. Кроме того, в устойчивом выражении, означающем 'умереть', тоже возможна замена: *заснуть вечным сном - уснуть вечным сном.*
Но значение 'умереть' присуще только одиночному глаголу *уснуть* (но не *заснуть*). У глагола уснуть есть и значение 'перестать проявляться; ослабеть, притупиться (о чувстве)'. Можно сказать: *Уснула ненависть. Уснуло горе. Уснула любовь.* Но не *Заснула ненависть, Заснуло горе, Заснула любовь.*

От глагола *заснуть* (СВ) образуется парный приставочный глагол НСВ - *засыпать*. А от глагола *уснуть* такое образование видовой пары невозможно.